# Rally Kanban board - include only certain tags

Tags: rally, kanban

Instead of filtering by a tag (and highlighting the stories with that tag), can I edit the code and only show stories with a specific tag on the Kanban board?

I found another question with this code (as a sample for another purpose):

```
      var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags.Name Contains "whatever");
```

Will this work? if so, where do I input this line of code? I've tried a few places with no success.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That query should work.  The Kanban app is built using the App SDK's CardBoard component, so you can simply specify a 'query' property on the config object passed to the constructor:

```
//Inside _redisplayBoard:
var cardboardConfig = {
   //...
   //Other existing config properties
   //...
   //Specify query
   query: new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags.Name Contains "whatever")
};
```

You can learn more about working with the Query utility here: http://developer.rallydev.com/help/utilities#Query

The CardBoard component is documented here:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/card-board

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work. Tags are objects and the Tags field on a User Story/Hierarchical Requirement is an array of Tag objects. The way I have been able to filter tags is to specify the _ref, which is the web service JSON result. It would look a bit like this:

```
var tag = {some tag object};

var tagFilter = [Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
    property: 'Tags',
    operator: 'contains',
    value: tag._ref
})];

var cardboardConfig = {
   //...
   //Other existing config properties
   //...
   //Specify filter
   storeConfig: {
       filters: tagFilter
   }
};
```